# Jenkins git plugin getting status code 128 with bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

sometimes when jenkins tries to checkout a repo from bitbucket it will give me error 128..

Im using an SSH key to authenticate and most of the time it works .. 
but tere are period that i get this error..

```
> Fetching upstream changes from
> git@bitbucket.org:team/myCoreRepo.git
>  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
>  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress git@bitbucket.org:team/myCoreRepo.git
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
>  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:team/myCoreRepo.git # timeout=10
>  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
>  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:team/myCoreRepo.git # timeout=10 Fetching
> upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:team/myCoreRepo.git
>  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress git@bitbucket.org:team/myCoreRepo.git
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin' hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch
> from git@bitbucket.org:team/myCoreRepo.git    at
> hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:904)  at
> hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1144)   at
> hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1175)  at
> org.jenkinsci.plugins.multiplescms.MultiSCM.checkout(MultiSCM.java:143)
>   at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)    at
> hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)  at
> hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
>   at
> jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>   at
> hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
>   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1816)  at
> hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
> hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>   at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429) Caused by:
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program
> Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress
> git@bitbucket.org:team/myCoreRepo.git
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: stdout:  stderr: Connection closed by 18.205.93.2 port 22 fatal: Could not read
> from remote repository.
> 
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

We also saw this behaviour when the Jenkins ran out of Disk Space.
So you might want to check that.